# ionic 2 cordova, install cordova plugin typings

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, typescript-typings

Hi I want to install the typings for cordova's InAppBrowser.

using

> typings install dt~cordova --save --global

somehow strips (by default) all other references and doesn't install the plugins.

How can I install them manually? I've tried

> typings install dt~cordova/plugins/InAppBrowser --save --global

and is says

> Unable to find "cordova/plugins/InAppBrowser" ("dt") in the registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install as  `typings install dt~cordova/plugins/inappbrowser --global`
Use lowercase as **"inappbrowser"** instead of "InAppBrowser"

Comment: thanks! do you know why why window.cordova.InAppBrowser doesn't compile?

Comment: Typescript cannot understand javascript. So we need to install typings for compilation. If you are using ionic2, then you can use ionic native instead of adding the typings.

Answer (score 2):

Use lowercase:

```
typings install dt~cordova/plugins/inappbrowser --save --global
```

Answer (score 1):

With TypeScript 2.0 you can use

```
npm install @types/cordova-plugins-inappbrowser --save-dev
```

see:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#definitelytyped-

Answer (score 0):

To use cordova in typescript Ionic 2.2.0 -----

```
npm i -g typings  // update typings, it might needed
typings install dt~cordova --global --save
```

and then uncomment it in **typings/index.d.ts**